# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS doesn't detect and connect to 2.4 GHz wifi but detects and connect to 5 GHz wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 with quick reboot turned off and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. For past few few months I am unable to connect to 2.4 GHz wifi while being in Ubuntu but can detect and connect to 5 GHz wifi networks. On the windows side, I can connect to both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz wifi smoothly. I have secure boot turned on. Here's the network adapter details :

```
:~$ iwlist frequency
lo        no frequency information.

enp4s0f1  no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 144 : 5.72 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.745 GHz (Channel 149)
```

Please help. It is the same with other Linux distributions also. While trying to install them, 2.4 GHz Wifi would work 1 out of 10 times and after 2-3 restarts, it would stop working.

Comment: What is the 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi channel used?

Comment: @Pilot6, How to find that ? It connects to my mobile.

Comment: Are you using your mobile as an AP?

Comment: No no, it's a dlink router.

Comment: @Pilot6, I found using windows, the channel number is 13. How can I get that in Ubuntu?

Comment: That's the problem. you have a region set that doesn't allow 12-13 channels. You'd better change it in router settings.

Comment: @Pilot6, is there any way to increase my channel numbers in Ubuntu?

Comment: It depends on hardware. And it is not the OS problem. You hardware is supposed to be used in the US or other country with these channels prohibited. But you can try `iw reg set`